# Is it possible to set a composite NOT NULL constraint in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, constraint

For logging purposes, in a table I design, I want to store the IP information of users when they logged in.

When a user logs in, IPv4, IPv6 or both IP addresses should be stored. But I want to set a constraint that both cannot be NULL.

Is it possible to do that in Standard SQL with constraints or should I do that using PL/pgSQL in PostgreSQL or in the business tier?

Comment: Why do you need two different columns? The `inet` data type can store IPv4 and IPv6 addresses in the same column: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-net-types.html#DATATYPE-INET

Comment: Can they be both `NOT NULL`? And what would that mean, can a user have 2 different IP addresses, one IP4 and one IP6?

Comment: @TypoCubeᵀᴹ Only one of them can be NULL.

Comment: I ask again: can they both be NOT NULL?

Comment: @TypoCubeᵀᴹ I am looking for the combination. Either (IPv4) or (IPv6) or (both IPv4 and IPv6 together) can have value(s). If both are NOT NULL, then I cannot have a situation such as IPv4 with a valid value and IPv6 with a NULL value. (It is just what I want. I don't discuss if it is the proper way to do it or not.) Did I understand your question right?

Comment: Yes, you answered my first question but not the second (about the meaning of when both values are NOT NULL). What would it mean for a user (would it be possible?) to login with 2 IP addresses, one in IPv4 and another in IPv6, that can be different? In any case, you have answers that cover all situations.

Comment: Both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses will point to the same location but I don't know if a developer can access either IPv4 or IPv6 addresses (or both) on the server side. So, I added two columns if it is possible to access and save both at the same time. It may be just a design mistake I made.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Let's assume the structure of your table is this one:

```
CREATE  TABLE log_logins 
(
    user_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    login_time TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
    ip_v4 TEXT /* or any other representation */,
    ip_v6 TEXT /* or any other representation */,
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id, login_time) 
) ;
```

You can just add a [`CHECK`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-constraints.html) that guarantees that either one of `ip_v4` or `ip_v6` is not null, but not both (it makes no sense to me to have *both* a v4 address and a v6 one; you don't normally use both protocols at the same time). That would be done with the following statement:

```
ALTER TABLE log_logins
  ADD CONSTRAINT one_and_only_one_of_ip_v4_or_ip_v6
  CHECK ((ip_v4 IS NULL) <> (ip_v6 IS NULL));
```

If it is reasonable to have *both* a v4 and a v6 address at the same time, the constraint to use would be:

```
ALTER TABLE log_logins
  ADD CONSTRAINT at_least_one_of_ip_v4_or_ip_v6
  CHECK ((ip_v4 IS NOT NULL) OR (ip_v6 IS NOT NULL));
```

---

Alternatively, take a look at the [**RhodiumToad/ip4r extension**](https://github.com/RhodiumToad/ip4r). If you use it, you can represent `ip4`, `ip6` or `ipaddress` (that can contain either an IPv4 or IPv6 address) in a compact and efficient way, and have a collection of operators on both IP addresses and IP address-ranges. I'd actually recommend it.

Although PostgreSQL includes the [`inet`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-net-types.html) data type, that can be used to store internet addresses (together with netmasks), the `ip4r` extension provides a few advantages if you *only* need an IP address (without the netmask). One of the advantage is a more compact representation, that may play a role if the volume of data to be recorded is big. This extension is really helpful if you need to use `ip ranges`. One use case would be to join the IP column of the `log_logins` table to another table containing (arbitrary) **IP ranges** and the countries to which they correspond.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and the link for ip4r extension.

Comment: No need for an extension, Postgres' `inet` data type can store ipv4 and ipv6 addresses.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Yes, it can, but read the _RATIONALE_ on https://github.com/RhodiumToad/ip4r, and you'll find that they have a different use-case, and some performance gains. This module is specially useful when you use not just IPs, but arbitrary ranges (for instance, when you want to JOIN an IP address on table a to a range of IPs on table b, that might be used, for instance, to assign countries to IP ranges). On the other hand, if you need to make huge logs, the data representation of IPs takes less space than that of INETs, and that _might_ count.

Answer (score 8):

Yes. It is. Just put a constraint on the table.

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE foo (
  userid serial PRIMARY KEY,
  ipv4   inet   CHECK (family(ipv4) = 4),
  ipv6   inet   CHECK (family(ipv6) = 6),
  CHECK (ipv4 IS NOT NULL OR ipv6 IS NOT NULL)
);
```

Or, you can just [use the same type (`inet`)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-net-types.html) which will support ipv4 or ipv6..

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE foo (
  userid   serial PRIMARY KEY,
  userip   inet   NOT NULL 
);
```

Comment: @ukll did you mark the right one

Comment: Yes, I am satisfied with your answer. But I accepted the other one for showing how to not accept both fields to have a value too (not for the external link) in addition to the answer of my question.

Comment: That's cool, didn't realize that's what you were looking for.

Answer (score -3):

This is my solution for sequelize **migration file** in "up" function

```
queryInterface.sequelize.getQueryInterface().addConstraint('log_logins', {
  fields: ['ipv4', 'ipv6'],
  type: 'check',
  name: 'ipv4_or_ipv6_is_null',
  where: { [Sequelize.Op.or]: [{ ipv4: null }, { ipv6: null }] },
}),
```

Comment: why not? :(((((